# java.net.URL removing portion of absolute path for `file` URL

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I'm trying to ensure that configuring the `ResourceHandlerRegistry` in my Spring Boot application will support static resources based on a path, e.g.:

```
registry
  .addResourceHandler("/static/**")
  .addResourceLocations("file:///home/alex");
```

However my resources are 404'ing, e.g. doing a GET `localhost:8080/static/blah/1234.txt` doesn't resolve.

I notice that stepping through the `PathResourceResolver` code it makes the following call:

```
Resource resource = location.createRelative(resourcePath);
```

which for a `file`-scheme URL results in calling `FileUrlResource.createRelative` which returns a new `FileUrlResource`:

```
return new FileUrlResource(new URL(getURL(), relativePath));
```

Which actually evaluates to an incorrect URL because the last portion of the absolute path from the URL returned from `getURL()` is truncated, e.g.:

```
new java.net.URL(new URL("file:///home/alex"), "blah.txt")
```

results in:

```
file:/home/blah.txt
```

which seems wrong to me.

Any ideas please?

Comment: Have you tried `new java.net.URL(new URL("file:///home/alex/", "blah.txt"))`

Comment: I swear I tried every other permutation but that. It worked - thank you!